# Change HTML code with jQuery & output it into textbox

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML-code:

```
<ul>
     <li class="1"><a>Option #1</a></li>
     <li class="2"><a>Option #2</a></li>
</ul>

<textarea>Output the changed HTML-code here</textarea>
```

I have jQuery script to change the `<li>` class name to "selected" on click:

```
$('ul li').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings('li').removeClass('selected');
});
```

After clicking, for example, Option #1, jQuery will change `<li>` class to "1 selected", and I need the following code to be outputed into the textarea:

```
<ul>
     <li class="1 selected"><a>Option #1</a></li>
     <li class="2"><a>Option #2</a></li>
</ul>
```

How do I output the modified HTML-code into textarea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing classes, select the desired parent element and substitute its HTML for the `textarea`'s:

```js
$('ul li').on('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings('li').removeClass('selected');
    $('textarea').html($(this).closest('.parent-element').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent-element">
    <ul>
        <li class="1"><a>Option #1</a></li>
        <li class="2"><a>Option #2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<textarea style="width: 100%; height: 400px;">Output the changed HTML-code here</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

here's an alternative for giggles:

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vjmurtxt/30/)

[image: select]

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function () {

    $(this)
        .addClass('selected')
        .siblings('li')
        .removeClass('selected')
        .parent()
        .next('textarea')
        .val($(this).text());

});
```